# When I use jdbc and phoenix to query data from hbase,the "resultset.first()" throw exception

Tags: jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

the code like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

the exception like this:

java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at com.salesforce.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixResultSet.first(PhoenixResultSet.java:173)

Comment: Please include the code in the question **as text**. Don't post screenshots of code. As to the problem: have you read the JDBC API Javadoc of [`ResultSet.first()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first--), especially _"SQLFeatureNotSupportedException - if the JDBC driver does not support this method"_? Apparently your driver doesn't support this, also note that unless you use scrollable result sets (which your code doesn't, and the driver likely doesn't support), that `first()` is supposed to throw an SQLException anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you recode your code to use `next()` instead of `first()` you'll be fine:

```
while(resultset.next()) {
  //Do something with resultset
}
```

If you're looking for the **why** though... you'll have to go and ask the developers of that JDBC driver. As positioning inside a `ResultSet` requires a *scrollable* `ResultSet`, it is possible that this feature simply is not there.

Comment: Thank you.Maybe,the"com.salesforce.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver" doesn`t support this.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation for ResultSet.first() is not yet done in Apache Phenix. Hence, you get the error.

```
 public boolean first() throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }
```

Try using ResultSet.next() function.